# if/then replace values looping over rows conditional on column value(s) in R

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, conditional-statements

I am trying to do an if/then replacement (recoding) of values row by row (looping over rows), based on one the values of or more columns in those rows. I've looked at a lot of prior examples here and elsewhere (R help) but haven't been able to get very far.

Here is an example data set:

```
> set.seed(1234)
> let<-c("AB","AA","BB")
> df <- data.frame(rbind(x1=c(12,"DF1",sample(let,6,TRUE)),x2=c(12,"HA.1",sample(let,6,TRUE)),x3=c(21,"DF1",sample(let,6,TRUE)),x4=c(12,"AS.2",sample(let,6,TRUE))
+ ))
> df
   X1   X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
x1 12  DF1 AB AA AA AA BB AA
x2 12 HA.1 AB AB AA AA BB AA
x3 21  DF1 AB BB AB BB AB AB
x4 12 AS.2 AB AB AB AB AB AB
```

I would like to conditionally change the coding (replace) values in columns 3:8 (from X3 through X8) based on values in X1 and X2 using if/then. 'AB' becomes 1 if X1=12 AND X2=DF1, 'AA' becomes 2 if X1=12 AND X2=DF1, 'BB' becomes 3 if X1=12 and X2=DF1 etc. There will be many other (nested?) if statements to add to complete this specific case, but I am not sure how to approach even the most basic aspect of this script: **how to condition the replacement of values in columns 3:8 based on the column 1 value (and also column 2 or more columns) at a given row.**

So, looping over each row, I would test if the value in X2 = DF1 and X1=12 (for example), and if so in both cases, change values of AB to 1, AA to 2, and BB to 3...

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
      if((df$X2[i]=="DF1") & (df$X1[i]=12)) {   
          ifelse(df[i,3:8] == "AB", 1, ifelse(df[i,3:8]=="AA", 2,ifelse(df[i,3:8]=="BB",3,"NA")))}
             else{} 
      }
```

Now...this appears to do nothing - no changes to `df`and no warnings. But the `ifelse` statements  work when I specify the row (4):

```
> ifelse(df[4,3:8] == "AB", 1, ifelse(df[4,3:8]=="AA", 2,ifelse(df[4,3:8]=="BB",3,"NA")))
   X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8 
x4 "1" "3" "1" "1" "1" "2"
> df[4,3:8]
   X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
x4 AB BB AB AB AB AA
```

So it must be something in the initial `if &`  ? Do I need to have something in my `else` clause?

And of course, my 'real' world use case is more complicated as each different value in X1 or X2 will require different if/then statements to recode the values in colum 3:8

Anyway - am I even approaching this correctly? Would a look up table work better? I would be setting up additional nested if/& statements for each combination of values for X1 and X2. It will be ugly, but if I can get the nested if statements to work, then at least I can get there.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the data in long format and then use separate `case_when` with conditions to recode values and finally get the data back in original format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(X1, X2)) %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(X1 == 12 & X2 == 'DF1' & value == 'AB' ~ 1,
                           X1 == 12 & X2 == 'DF1' & value == 'AA' ~ 2, 
                           X1 == 12 & X2 == 'DF1' & value == 'BB' ~ 3, 
                           #Add more conditions as per requirements
                           #....
                           #If none of the above condition satisfy 
                           #return a default value
                           TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider()
```

`case_when` is an alternative to nested `ifelse` statements since it makes to easy to write for various conditions in simple steps.

Comment: Cool! dplyr/tidyr is something I hadn't really considered (dont use that often). Very 'tidy'.  One thing I noticed is that when the code is run,  warnings are thrown:  'Values in `value` are not uniquely identified...' as theDF1 value is found more than once? The tibble produced  has two values in each cell for DF1 (one from each instance found):

Comment: @user95146 yes, probably. in that case try  `df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(X1, X2, -row)) %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(X1 == 12 & X2 == 'DF1' & value == 'AB' ~ 1,
                           ...conditions....
                           TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider()`

Comment: ```>tibble
 X1   X2   X3   X4   X5   X6   X7   X8
1 12  DF1 1, 1 2, 3 2, 1 2, 3 3, 1 2, 1
2 12 HA.1   11   11   10   10    9   10
3 12 AS.2    0    0    0    0    0    0 ```

Comment: It is not clear in comments what you are trying to show. Did you try my above suggestion? Did it work?

Comment: Sorry, was trying to show the tibble and the duplicated values. I did try the updated suggestion (just added this to 2nd line of code): ```mutate(row = row_number()) %>%``` , but it gave me this error: "Error: No common type for `X3` <character> and `row` <integer>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred." Perhaps I am not adding it in the right place ? (the line after  or just after df %>%)

Comment: `df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(X1, X2, row)) %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(X1 == 12 & X2 == 'DF1' & value == 'AB' ~ 1,
                           X1 == 12 & X2 == 'DF1' & value == 'AA' ~ 2, 
                           X1 == 12 & X2 == 'DF1' & value == 'BB' ~ 3, 
                           TRUE ~0)) %>%
  pivot_wider()` works for the given example.

Answer (score 1):

```r
if((df$X2[i]=="DF1") & (df$X1[i]=12))
```

In the second comparison you are using `=` instead of `==`. Also, you are not assigning anything within your loop, that is why nothing is happening.

But iterating over rows of a data frame in R is generally not a good idea as it is not very performant. Furthermore, `ifelse()` already provides a vectorized solution. But unfortunately, you are not using it right, as you need to apply it to each of the columns you are working on.

I think the best solution for what you are trying to do would be the following:

```r
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(12, 12, 21, 12), 
                     X2 = c("DF1", "HA.1", "DF1", "AS.2"), 
                     X3 = c("AB", "AB", "AB", "AB"), 
                     X4 = c("AA", "AB", "BB", "AB"), 
                     X5 = c("AA", "AA", "AB", "AB"), 
                     X6 = c("AA", "AA", "BB", "AB"), 
                     X7 = c("BB", "BB", "AB", "AB"), 
                     X8 = c("AA", "AA", "AB", "AB")), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)
                )
df
#>   X1   X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
#> 1 12  DF1 AB AA AA AA BB AA
#> 2 12 HA.1 AB AB AA AA BB AA
#> 3 21  DF1 AB BB AB BB AB AB
#> 4 12 AS.2 AB AB AB AB AB AB

rows <- df$X2 == "DF1" & df$X1 == 12
df[rows, 3:8] <- lapply(df[rows, 3:8], function(x) {as.integer(factor(x, c("AB", "AA", "BB")))})
df
#>   X1   X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
#> 1 12  DF1  1  2  2  2  3  2
#> 2 12 HA.1 AB AB AA AA BB AA
#> 3 21  DF1 AB BB AB BB AB AB
#> 4 12 AS.2 AB AB AB AB AB AB
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You need to make sure here, that your variables are characters, not factors or it won't work.

You could also do it with nested `ifelse()` calls, as you did before, but it is already pretty verbose for just three.

---

**Edit in response to comment:**

```r
# Unite the group vars in one vector
group <- paste(df$X1, df$X2, sep = "-")

# In this list you can say what case should use what recoding
lst <- list("12-DF1" = c("AB" = 1, "AA" = 2, "BB" = 3), 
            "12-HA.1" = c("AB" = 5, "AA" = 3, "BB" = 4), 
            "21-DF1" = c("AB" = 8, "AA" = 22, "BB" = 11), 
            "12-AS.2" = c("AB" = 9, "AA" = 7, "BB" = 6))

# Function to recode single column
rcde_cols <- function(column) mapply(function(col, g) {unlist(lst[[g]][col])}, 
                                     col = as.list(column), 
                                     g = as.list(group))

# Apply to all
df[3:8] <- lapply(df[3:8], rcde_cols)
```

Comment: Ah. Ok. This works nicely in this case, but the more specific use case will require recoding e.g. row 2 (X1=12, X2 =HA.1) where now AB = 5, AA=3, and BB =4 (different re coding based on different values for X1 and X2). Is there a more general way to set up a series of nested ```ifelse()``` calls for additional recodings?                                                 With your approach, id need  a different ```rows``` object for each potential coding.

Comment: How get the same result as the answer but with nested ```ifelse()``` calls?